# can I set sysdate as default value on a Slick table's date column

Tags: slick

I have a requirement on adding a date column to a table with default value is set by oracle's sysdate as follows

EXAMPLE {
...
CREATED_ON DATE  DEFAULT SYSDATE
}

I want to use slick table ddl to create the table using

```
object ExampleTable extends Table[...]("EXAMPLE") {
def createdOn = column[java.sql.Date]("CREATED_ON", Default (?))
}
```

it seems there is no available sysdate for the default value, should I handle this default value programmatically or is there still a way using Slick?

Thanks,

Comment: Why there is no feature like Ebean default value?
As mentioned in the source code [v1.0.1] the column option should have the same type as the column type, so I think there is no way to do that, at least for now^^.

case class Default[T](val defaultValue: T) extends ColumnOption[T]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to use O.Default for your situation.  When trying O.Default(new Date()), it would default the field to the date the ddl was executed, and not to sysdate.

I think the easiest workaround would be to use DBType to define the entire column, i.e.

```
def createdOn = column[java.sql.Date]("CREATED_ON", DBType("date default sysdate"))
```

You can verify this by inspecting the ExampleTable.ddl object.